# TweenLite - Animation Adding More Pixels Than Specified

Tags: jquery, css, animation, gsap

I am creating a vertical carousel that consists of 4 sections. I have an outer-wrapper set to the full height and width of the window and an inner-wrapper absolutely positioned inside this outer-wrapper.

I am trying to animate it on mousewheel scroll, but it is adding too many pixels?

Here is the code for the mousewheel event: (I am using a scrolling plugin)

```
$('.carousel-outer-wrapper').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
        var carousel = $('.carousel-wrapper');
        TweenLite.to(carousel, 1, {top: "+=50px"});
    });
```

I would expect it to add only 50px when I scroll the wheel but it always adds more (any random number between 50px and about 73px). The fact that the numbers aren't in multiples of 50 also suggests the mousewheel scrolling isnt just running too many times.

How can I ensure the carousel will only slide exactly 50px ?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, when you use **mousewheel** for the first time and scroll only once just slightly, the carousel executes fine and adds **50px** to its **top** position. But when the animation is in progress and if you add another **mousewheel** event to it, the carousel adds another **50px** to your currently running animation and the end result becomes **a 50px addition to the existing position which was still in progress**. This is the part you are having trouble with right? You always want **multiples of 50px** in terms of destination **top** value?

Comment: Yes, what I am trying to achieve is when the user scrolls the mousewheel it scrolls the slider by exactly the amount of pixels specified.

Comment: I think then caching the destination values to a globally defined variable, and adding more to that variable on each **mousescroll** would help you here. For example, if `destTop` is your global (or within a certain scope) variable. Then on each **mousewheel** event, you do `destTop += 50;`, that would help. In your `TweenLite`, you would only animate to a `destTop` value. Getting?

Comment: Or you could make sure that the tween doesn't fire when it is being executed. And only execute the Tween when it rests.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a solution to my problem.

It doesn't explain why the animation was adding extra pixels that were not multiples of 50, but it does stop the slider from running the function multiple times.

I changed my code to the following and it now works:

```
    var blockedSlider = false;

    $('.carousel-outer-wrapper').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
        if (blockedSlider == false) {
            blockedSlider = true;
            var carousel = $('.carousel-wrapper');
            TweenLite.to(carousel, 1, {top: "-=50px", onComplete:function() {               
                blockedSlider = false;
            }});            
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options in my humble opinion:

- Only tween when the animation is at rest.
- Use a global variable as a
  destination value, add (or remove) to that variable. And `TweenLite`
  would only use that variable as its destination.

**Example #1:**

```
if (!TweenMax.isTweening(carousel)) { // only execute when the tween on this object is not running
  // your code for tween goes here.
}
```

**Example #2:**

```
destY = 0;
$('.carousel-outer-wrapper').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
  destY += 50;
  var carousel = $('.carousel-wrapper');
  TweenLite.to(carousel, 1, {top: destY});
});
```